# using files with express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    db = require('./db'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    controller = require('./controller');


app.use(express.static('../public'));

app.get('/server', function (req, res) {
  console.log(__dirname);
    res.sendFile('/../client/index.html');
});
```

I have this express server set up but using the code above I get "Cannot GET /" when I view localhost:*portnumber*.  If I change the GET method to:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '../client/index.html');
});
```

I get "'C:\Users\TC\Documents\Desktop\myapp\multiplayerWebSite\server..\client\index.html' at Error (native)"  and if I change it to:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('../client/index.html');
});
```

I get "TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile"
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

The server was working perfectly when I had everything in the root directory, but I wanted to change the folder structure to make it more neat/professional.  If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it greatly.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use path module, there is a join method that take multiple paths to make one.

Exemple if you do:

```
path.join('test/musicfolder', '../videofolder/allreadyseen')
```

you will get `'test/videofolder/allreadyseen'` .

you can see all the doc here : https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    app = express(),
    db = require('./db'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    controller = require('./controller');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

app.get('/server', function (req, res) {
  console.log(__dirname);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much; it's using my html file now, but what about the static files?  It isn't using working for my css file that's stored in ../public/css

Comment: use path.join too and see my exemple if you want to understand what it's doing

Comment: I've read the path.join documentation but it isn't helping me with the static files.  Using path.join(__dirname, '../public') isn't working.  Neither is path.join(__dirname, '../public/css'), even if I append '/styles.css' to the file path.  I hate to keep asking for help.

Comment: I'm constantly trying to fix it if that makes me less annoying.  I'm not just dicking around waiting for someone to give me an answer.

Comment: can you create a tree of your folders? so that I can see how can work with path

Comment: -rootDir
--client
  --index.html
--lib
  --jquery.min.js
--public
  --css
    --styles.css
  --js
--server
  --server.js

Comment: so server.js and public folder are in same folder?

Comment: Damn it...  rootDir( client (index.html), lib (jquery.min.js), public (css (styles.css), js (empty for now) ), server (server.js) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123585/discussion-between-gatsbill-and-j3ssi3ftw).

Comment: No.  Sorry if that format is bad.  I used shift+enter to try and build a legible hierarchy but apparently it doesnt support that format....